# Avoid Runtime Error on Range Selection from WS already declared and set

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have this code and it is working fine if I run the macro while Sheet1 is selected or activated.
However it fails when other sheets are selected. Why?
I get a:

> Runtime Error: Select method of range class failed

Isn't it covered when I `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:M" & lrow).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I improve the code and avoid the `Runtime Error`? 
What am I missing? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to select the range? Why not directly work with it? [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: i did that actually :) problem is i need to preserve the data format of the values. so i try the select and do the paste special. is there a way to directly copy and paste to ranges and preserve data format?

Comment: Yup there is. Where do you want to copy `.Range("A1:M" & lrow)` to?

Comment: to itself. it contains formula, so i want to preserve the data format of values i get from the formula and paste it as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to itself. it contains formula, so i want to preserve the data format of values i get from the formula and paste it as values. –  L42 1 min ago

Like I mentioned, you can avoid the use of `.Select` in most of the cases.

Is this what you are trying?

Replace

```
.Range("A1:M" & lrow).Select
```

with

```
.Range("A1:M" & lrow).Value  = .Range("A1:M" & lrow).Value
```

Or maybe this?

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:M" & lrow).Copy
        .Range("A1:M" & lrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah, that's what i'm using. unfortunately i have a long number in a form of string (value i get from the formula). that code changes that value into numbers instead of text.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that string? so I can test it before updating the above post

Comment: any long number.(eg. 250000326959205128).

Comment: haha it works as usual. that argument doesn't came out when i first tried it. i used '(' as oppose to hitting space. LOL.